# Memory Address Translation in OS

Tags: operating-system

Is Memory address translation only useful when the total size of virtual memory
(summed over all processes) needs to be larger than physical memory?

Comment: There's no direct relation between the size of physical memory and the size of virtual memory. The latter can be smaller than, equal to, or greater than the former.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the size of virtual memory depends on what you call "virtual memory". If you call virtual memory the virtual memory of one process then virtual memory has the same size than physical memory. If you call virtual memory the whole virtual memory of all processes than virtual memory can (technically) have an infinite size. This is because every process can have a whole address space. The virtual address space of one process cannot be bigger than physical memory because the processor has limited bits to address this memory. In modern long mode the processor has only 48 bits to address RAM at the byte level. This gives a very big amount of RAM but most systems will have 8GB to 32GB.

Technically on a 8GB RAM computer, every process could have 8GB allocated. I say technically because eventually, the computer will constantly be removing page frames from RAM and that will put too much overhead on the OS and on the computer which will make your system freeze. In the end, the size of the sum of the virtual memory of every process is limited by the capacity of your system (and OS) to have an efficient page swapping algorithm (and on your willingness to have a slow system).

Now to answer your question, paging (virtual memory) is used also to avoid fragmentation and for securing the system. With the old segmentation model, fragmentation was an issue because you had to run a complex algorithm to determine which part of memory a process gets. With paging, the smallest granularity of memory is 4KB. This makes everything much easier because a small process just gets a 4KB page and the process can work in that page the way it wants. While a bigger process will get several pages and can allocate more pages by doing a system call. There is still the issue of external fragmentation but it is mostly due to latency of accessing high memory vs low memory. Basically, paging solves the issue of external fragmentation because a process can get a page anywhere (where it's available) and it will not make a difference (except for high vs low memory). There is still the issue of internal fragmentation with paging.

Paging also secures the system. With segmentation you had several levels of ring protection. With paging you have only user or supervisor. With segmentation, the memory is not well protected because one process can access the memory of another process in the same segment. With paging, there are 2 different protections. The first protection is the ring itself (user vs supervisor) the second are the page tables. The page tables isolate one process from another because the memory accesses are translated to other positions in RAM. It is the job of the OS to fill the page tables properly so that one process doesn't have access to the physical memory allocated to another process. The user vs supervisor bit in the page tables, prevent one process from accessing the kernel except via a system call interface (the instruction syscall in assembly for x86).